# can not get json from php to html (sometimes works and sometimes not..)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I need some help...

I have 2 files:

- form.html that contains the html form
- register.php- gets the post request from the form, registers the user in the database and returns json that contains all the registered users (I want to display them in form.html right after a successful registration).

my problem:

I catched the submit event and made a post request to register.php.
The register file works fine and regiters users to the db. the problem is to get the json with all the registers users from register.php to form.html.
You can see that I tried to alert the json by `alert(json)` in the callback function just to check if it came ok.
But when I run the code I was surprised to see that the line `alert(json)` sometimes works and somtimes not with no rational reason...
I just want be clear: the line `alert("inserting")` and the actual user registration to the DB works fine. The problem is in the callback function... Perhaps the problem is related to the end of the register file (the creation of the json).

thanks from advance!

form.html

```
        $( "#myForm" ).submit(function( event ) {
                        if(!validateForm()) //there is error
                        {
                            event.preventDefault();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            alert("inserting");

                            $(function(){
                                $('#myForm[name=new_post]').submit(function(){
                                  $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(json) {
                                    alert(json);
                                  }, 'json');
                                  return false;
                                });
                            });
                        }
        });
```

form definition:    `<form class="form-horizontal" id="myForm" role="form" method="POST" action="register.php">`

register.php

```
<?php
    $srevernme = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "mydb";
    //create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($srevernme,$username,$password,$dbname);

    //check connection
    if($conn->connect_error)
        die("connection failed:". $conn->connect_error);

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") 
    {        
        if (isset($_POST["fnameInput"]) && isset($_POST["lnameInput"]) && isset($_POST["addressInput"]) && isset($_POST["cityInput"]) && isset($_POST["zipcodeInput"]))
        {
            //add new users
            // prepare and bind
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name, address, city, zipcode) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
            if ($stmt == FALSE)
                die("Connection failed:");
            $stmt->bind_param("sssss",$firstname,$lastname,$address,$city,$zipcode);
            $firstname = $_POST["fnameInput"];
            $lastname = $_POST["lnameInput"];
            $address = $_POST["addressInput"];
            $city = $_POST["cityInput"];
            $zipcode = $_POST["zipcodeInput"];
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->close();


            //get all registers users

            $stmt2 = $conn->prepare("SELECT last_name,first_name FROM users ORDER BY last_name");
            if ($stmt2 == FALSE)
                die("Connection failed:");
            $stmt2->execute();                   
            $result = $stmt2->get_result();

            $arrayFormat = array();
            while($row = $result ->fetch_assoc())
            { 
                $arr = array('last_name'=>$row['last_name'],'first_name'=>$row['first_name']);
                $tmp_json = json_encode($arr);
                array_push($arrayFormat,$tmp_json);  
            }
            echo json_encode($arrayFormat, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);

            $stmt2->close();
        }
    }

    $conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Are you always sure you're getting to the third `if` statement. Remember, an `if` statement inherently means there is an else whether or not you specify a condition for it or not. In this case you have 3 `if` statements only one of which has a `json_encode` and three unspecified `else` cases that could occur, are not dealt with and don't `json_encode` anything. If you always want `json` returned, then handle your errors gracefully by returning `json` that has for instance a status which could be `error` and a `message`describing the error.

Comment: To confirm that the problem is not on server side, do you see in the console/dev tools of your browser the JSON response in the 'Network' tab ? (here is how it looks with Chrome https://developer.chrome.com/devtools#improving-network-performance)

Comment: On a different note, what comes back when you use `alert(json);`? If it is truly an object in the right format, you should be getting `[object Object]` or `[array Object]`, as oppose to anything useful. I'd use `console.log(json);` to see a more useful layout of the data.

Comment: @ValLeNain Yes I see the json on  the  'Network' tab. To be more specific: I also see the json in the browser as html (the url changes to register.php) instead of returning the json to form.html and handle it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the server side, Try this:

```
if($conn->connect_error):
    die("connection failed:". $conn->connect_error);
endif;
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"): 
   if (isset($_POST["fnameInput"]) && isset($_POST["lnameInput"]) 
       && isset($_POST["addressInput"]) && isset($_POST["cityInput"]) 
       && isset($_POST["zipcodeInput"])):
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` 
                (first_name, last_name, address, city, zipcode) 
                VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        if ($stmt == FALSE):
            die("Connection failed:");
        endif;            
        $stmt->bind_param("sssss",$firstname,$lastname,$address,$city,$zipcode);
        $firstname = $_POST["fnameInput"];
        $lastname = $_POST["lnameInput"];
        $address = $_POST["addressInput"];
        $city = $_POST["cityInput"];
        $zipcode = $_POST["zipcodeInput"];
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
        $stmt2 = $conn->prepare("SELECT last_name,first_name 
                                 FROM `users` ORDER BY last_name");
        if ($stmt2 == FALSE):
            die("Connection failed:");
        endif;
        $stmt2->execute();                   
        $result = $stmt2->get_result();
  $formatArray= array();
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()):
     array_push($formatArray, $row); //push result to $formatArray     
  endwhile;
  echo json_encode($formatArray, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
  $stmt2->close();
 endif;    
endif;
$conn->close();
```

And for client side:

```
var form = $("#myForm");
$('#myForm[name=new_post]').submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
 $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"register.php",
        data:form.serialize(),
        dataType:"json", 
        success: function(json){ 
        if(json){
            var len = json.length;//we calculate the length of the json
            var txt = "";//open a blank txt variable
            if(len > 0){ //if length is greater than zero
               for(var i=0;i<len;i++){ //as long as len is greater than i variable
                 if(json[i].first_name && json[i].last_name){
                 //we start storing the json data into txt variable
                     txt += "<tr><td>"+json[i].last_name+"</td>
                                  <td>"+json[i].first_name+"</td>
                             </tr>";
                   }
                }
            if(txt != ""){ 
            //If data is there we remove the hidden attribute
            //and append the txt which contains the data into the table
            //The table is given an id named 'table'.
               $("#table").append(txt).removeClass("hidden");
            }
         }
      }
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert('error: ' + textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
     }       
 });
});
```

Before submitting the form you may like to hide your table, so in your css, add `.hidden{display:none;}`, then below the form in form.html.

```
<table id="table" class="hidden">       
    <tr>
        <th>First name</th>
        <th>Last name</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks for your try.. your code is just changing the format of the json but the real problam still exists..I  see the json in the browser as html (the url changes to register.php) instead of returning the json to form.html and handle it there.

Comment: Ok...let me try. Instead of console.logging, you put the json result into a div with a specific id. I will update my answer. Now How do you want to display all the users in form.html? In a table or a normal list?

Comment: Thanks. I need to display the users in a table.

Comment: sorry but it does not work...I want to be clear:I think that the `echo` command changes my url from `form.html` to `register.php` instead of returning the json to **form.html** and handle it there. In this link you can see what happens after the submission: [link](http://s31.postimg.org/5oy6b1zcr/tmp.jpg). Thanks again!

Comment: `echo json_encode($formatArray, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);` in the server side code

Comment: Add `return false` before the last }); in the jquery and remove e.preventDefault() e inside the function. CLear your browser cache as well. `echo` does not change your url.

Answer (score 0):

I recomend you use the promise interface like so:

```
var jqXHR = $.post(url, data);
jqXHR.done(function(){
    console.log(jqXHR.responseText); //check php notices...
    console.info(jqXHR.responseJSON); //all ok
})
.fail(function(){
    console.error(jqXHR.responseText); // here you will likely find your problem
});
```

most likely you have some warning or error in your php side and it will show up on the `fail` callback. Also check your Network tab on chrome for http statuses other than 2XX.